# Mode to set Directory in Only READ-WRITE mode

Tags: linux, directory

Can anyone tell me how to set a directory only in read/write mode as below?

```
-rw-rw-r--
```

I tried with 640,644 but I am able to achieve...

Comment: Usually, one does not set a directory to a permission that does not include the appropriate execute bit(s) set. "Execute" on a directory means approximately "access the contents"; "read" on a directory likewise means "enumerate the contents". If anything, on directories, **execute without read is a lot more common than read without execute.**

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
r - 4
w - 2
x - 1
```

For setting it as -rw-rw-r--, you need to run,

```
$ chmod 0664 <dir-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need `-rw-rw-r--`try to set mode `664`.

Comment: No if set 664 i am getting drw-rwSr--

Comment: @user1660325 `rw-rwSr--` is `2664`. Are you absolutely sure that you are using exactly `644`? If so, you may want to try `0644` instead. (Note that 2664 doesn't have any execute bits set.)

Comment: 0644 also no luck its giving drw-r-Sr--.

Comment: @user1660325: Try `chmod ug=rw,o=r <directory>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use this technique to change the access mode of directory/file.

```
4 - read
2 - write
1 - execute
```

So, if you want only read and write permission the you can go for 4+2 = 6 (read/write)
According to you question the command is

```
# chmod 664 <file/directory-name>
```